# Creating Soccerleagueranking with Codeigniter & Mysql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, ranking

I've searched the site for similar posts but i found just one where the developer tried to do his calculations (win-lose-draws) with an enormous SQL query. I would like to do the calculations in my controller but don't really know where to start.

I have 2 tables which look like this:

Teams

```
teamID     teamName
```

Games

```
gameID     matchday     homeTeamID     awayTeamID    homeScore     awayScore
```

Now i'm trying to produce a league ranking out of this match results, But i need some insights on how to look at this...

At the moment, I have a query which selects all the match results and assigns the correct teamID's to the home or away Team like this:

```
"SELECT g.gameID, g.matchday, g.homeTeamID, g.awayTeamID, g.homeScore, g.awayScore, th.teamName as homeTeam, ta.teamName as awayTeam,
FROM games AS g
INNER JOIN teams as th ON g.homeTeamID = th.teamID
INNER JOIN teams as ta ON g.awayTeamID = ta.teamID
JOIN submenu_teams AS s ON g.submenuID = s.submenuID"
```

Can anybody try to explain where to go from here to get a nice ranking of the teams according to how many points they won during the season?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to keep track of the points in a table (season1) so that every time a page is requested, you don't have to compute the rankings again : you just fetch from the table.

Everytime a new match is played, run a script that adds X point to winner and substracts Y points from loser.

To display, fetch the results and order by score.

You're done !

(was it my post that you read on rankings and SQL ?)

Comment: no it was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876219/complicated-football-league-dynamic-ordering-in-mysql) one. Which one is yours?
So basically your idea is to make a new table (a real ranking) and everytime one of the admins adds a few games, a script runs and inserts points to the database? That's ofcourse one possible solution, didn't even thought of that in the first place :). Thanks already @Cystack

Comment: yes if your admins use a web interface to add entries, right after adding each new result, you load the ranking table with the 2 new values (if it s soccer then it is either +3/0 0/+3 or +1/+1 i guess).